# jmx_prometheus_javaagent configuration for Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect

The Prometheus jmx_exporter project gives an official example configuration for Kafka here:

https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml

Is there any similar configuration for Kafka Connect to export Kafka Connect JMX metrics to Prometheus?

Comment: did u find the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solution that I'm using is the official Confluent Helm Charts and Docker image which has built-in Prometheus metric export:

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect

For reference, if you want a non-Docker, non-Kubernetes solution, a previous approach that works 100% is as follows:

1) Define this file `kafka-connect-jmx.yaml`. I am storing this config file in `/usr/share/`, you can put it elsewhere, but you will need to change the path reference below.

```
whitelistObjectNames: ["kafka.connect:*"]
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false

rules:
  - pattern: 'status: running'
    value: 1
  - pattern: 'status: *'
    value: 0
  - pattern: ".*"
```

2) Download `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.12.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar`. I put it in `/usr/share/`, you can put it elsewhere, but you will need to update the path in step 3.

3) When you run Kafka Connect `connect-distributed` make sure this environment variable is set and the paths match those used in steps 1+2

```
KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/usr/share/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=7072:/usr/share/kafka-connect-jmx.yaml
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same and found below. Hope that helps :)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zenreach/docker-kafka-connect/master/jmx_exporter.yaml

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
  - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-node-metrics, client-id=(.+), node-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_node_$3
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
      nodeId: "$2"
  - pattern: kafka.connect<type=connect-coordinator-metrics, client-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)thu
    name: kafka_connect_coordinator_$2
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
  - pattern: kafka.consumer<type=consumer-node-metrics, client-id=(.+), node-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_consumer_node_$3
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
      nodeId: "$2"
  - pattern: kafka.consumer<type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_consumer_fetch_manager_$3
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
      topic: "$2"
  - pattern: kafka.producer<type=producer-topic-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_producer_topic_$3
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
      topic: "$2"
  - pattern: kafka.producer<type=producer-node-metrics, client-id=(.+), node-id=(.+)><>([a-z-]+)
    name: kafka_connect_producer_node_$3
    labels:
      clientId: "$1"
      nodeId: "$2"
```